# Looking for OS X utility to verify/validate copied files/directories - checksum / SFV / MD5

Tags: macos, checksum, md5

Looking for the best way to easily validate the integrity of files/folder in OS X when copied from one location to another.

I've downloaded [SuperSFV](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/23168/supersfv) but it appears to be very slow.  Also new to the concept of checksums, so looking for easiest/best practice to ensure that a copied directory or file(s) are identical on the destination as they were on the source.

Answer (score 6):

There is a brew package [cksfv](http://brewformulas.org/Cksfv) which can do the trick. Works on Yosemite.

Install using [brew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install cksfv
```

Install using [Boxen](https://github.com/boxen/our-boxen), using brew:

```
# Add this to your Puppetfile:
github "homebrew"

# Add to your personal manifest:
package { 'cksfv': ensure => present }
```

Create a .sfv file:

```
# one file
cksfv myfile.zip > myfile.zip.sfv

# many files
cksfv file1.zip file2.zip > my-two-files.sfv

# all files
cksfv * > all-files-in-this-dir.sfv
```

Verify a .sfv file:

```
cksfv -f myfile.zip.sfv
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the checksum of a file by typing in Terminal :

```
md5 myfile.ext
```

Example :

```
user1@machine ~ $ md5 myfile.ext 
MD5 (myfile.ext) = d7badf415dbd52c2c8b51e564baef8be
```

edit:

For all files in a directory :

```
for file in * ; do md5 $file; done
```

Comment: how would I process an entire folder?

Comment: for file in * ; do md5 $file; done

Comment: Thanks - now how do I (simply) run and compare it on the destination once copied?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC digest commands have been invoked slightly different in some versions of OSX. I'm talking like, Tiger as opposed to Snow Leopard, but I still know some people using Tiger.
So, just in case 'md5' doesn't work by itself, try:

> `openssl md5 myfile.ext`

[edit]

And, FWIW, I have a bash alias in my .bashrc:

> `alias md5sum='openssl md5'`

It just fits better with my Linux habits.

Comment: "digests have changed in some versions of OSX" are you mad ? MD5 is a well defined hash algrorithm ! It will be full of nonsense to change it !

Comment: Ugh. Sorry. Totally not what I meant. What I mean is that digest commands changed.

I seem to remember a day when a bare `md5` command at the standard command line didn't work, and you had to do `openssl md5 file.ext`, or, `openssl` then `md5 file.ext` at the `OpenSSL>` prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `crc32 <FILE>` program can be used to get the `SFV`.

Or you can use:

- `md5 <FILE>`
- `cksum <FILE>`